# Port .htaccess rewrite rule to Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm moving from Apache to Nginx and would like to 'port' a rule from my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) slim/index.php [QSA,L]
```

How can I do this in Nginx?

An example of a request-url that should be re-written:
    http://my-app.development:8001/api/user/1

**Current behaviour**: My current Nginx server block changes (in my browser's address bar) the above request-url to:
    http://my-app.development/slim/index.php/api/user/1

**Desired behaviour**:
- Don't (visibly) change the request-url
- Use the slim/index.php file instead of index.php to process the (api) request

Current Nginx serverblock:

```
server {
    listen 8001;

    server_name my-app.development;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-app.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/my-app.error.log;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) /slim/index.php last;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass my-app:9000;

        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `rewrite...last` instead of `rewrite...break`.

Comment: I can see the url change in my browser's address bar (to /slim/index.php/api/...). I would have thought that this wouldn't happen. In fact I thought that it would redirect internally. It's still not working though, but I think it's because the required port (8001) is not used in this re-written url. Also I find it strange that the 'api' part isn't removed from the re-written url.

Comment: You need to edit your question with the configuration you are actually testing and the results you are getting. Access log entries will also be helpful.

Comment: The behavior you describe does not correspond to the nginx configuration you posted. Please post the _complete_ `server` block and describe the behavior you observe with it, along with the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is the very strange

```
        try_files $uri $uri/;
```

in your `location ~ \.php$` block.

This will cause index processing to run, which means that for a URL that doesn't correspond to a static file, nginx will start a new request for `index.php`. This probably won't do what you want.

This *should* read:

```
        try_files $uri =404;
```

This is a [security measure](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) and should read exactly as shown.

Once that's fixed, if you still are getting redirected in the browser, you should check your application.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this, but my browser keeps redirecting (as stated in my question-post). I clearly see a 301 in my Chrome developer bar. As my Nginx setup is the latest Alpine version from Docker Hub, I begin to think that I need to enable some other setting to let this work correctly? (PS, I've updated my question with the requested changes)

Comment: I don't think my application is causing the redirect as I've added a PHP die() statement in both my index.php & slim/index.php files. I've did some further reading and normally the redirect shouldn't happen because I don't have the 'permanent' flag and I'm not using an absolute URL in the rewritten url

Comment: Did you remember to clear your browser cache? Remember that a 301 redirect can be cached forever.

Comment: Clearing the browser cache did the trick! Thanks a lot! :)